# Ruby on Rails Pinterest button Media Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, pinterest

I have a blog using ruby on rails and haml
i added the pinterest button to the template so it appears in every post. now i want the preview image of the blog post to be automatically inserted in the media parameter.
i just cant figure out how to get the preview image or (if this isnt possible with rails/haml) the first image of the post to be displayed in the pinterest pop-up. thanks for helping!

```
%a.pinterest-share-button{:title => "Pin It", 
                          :class => "pin-it-button", 
                          :href => "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=#{request.url}&media{CODE HERE}&description=#{@post.title}", 
                          :rel => "nofollow", 
                          :target => "_blank", 
                          "count-layout" => "horizontal"} 
<img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
```

Comment: How do you normally grab the preview image?